# Diamondback, rosmake openni_kinect On fedora 15

Tags: ros, openni-kinect, fedora

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I try to compile openni_kinect drivers with GCC 4.6, but have next problem:

```
/home/crady/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl/ros/conversions.h: In function ‘void pcl::toROSMsg(const CloudT&, sensor_msgs::Image&) [with CloudT = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>, sensor_msgs::Image = sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >]’:
  /home/crady/ros/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/src/tools/convert_pcd_to_image.cpp:75:32:   instantiated from here
  /home/crady/ros/perception_pcl/pcl/include/pcl/ros/conversions.h:285:9: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

As I understand, I should add [-fpermissive] flag to some CMake file, to change error status to warning. But I can't find appropriate files. Can anybody help with this?
This flag actual for GCC 4.6, but can't downgrade to, for example, GCC 4.5.
Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11109/diamondback,-rosmake-openni_kinect-on-fedora-15/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2011-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it!
File ~/ros/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt has at the top next lines:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4.6)
    include ($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
    #set (ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
    set (ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)
    rosbuild_init ()
    rosbuild_add_boost_directories ()
    #add_definitions (-Wall -O3 -funroll-loops)
    rosbuild_check_for_sse ()
```

So, you should uncomment line "add_definitions" and add flag -fpermissive, like this:

```
add_definitions (-Wall -O3 -funroll-loops -permissive)
```

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2